# How to read XML file in Stored Procedure in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to consume an XML file from a folder and perform some transformations on specific tag values (say EventName value to "LOADSTOPAPP"), assign to a temp variable, and then insert the temp variable into a dummy table.

How can I do that, with this sample XML?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CISDocument>
    <EventName>LoadStopAppointment</EventName>
    <ReasonCode>APH_</ReasonCode>
    <ReasonCodeDescription>Appointment Changed</ReasonCodeDescription>
    <SystemTimeZoneOffset>0.000000</SystemTimeZoneOffset>
    <EventDateTime>2016-03-30T16:48:30</EventDateTime>
    <EventReportedDateTime>2016-03-30T16:48:30</EventReportedDateTime>
    <EventOccurredDateTime>2016-03-30T16:48:30</EventOccurredDateTime>
 </CISDocument>
```

Comment: How far have you got? Can you read the file into a PL/SQL variable (varchsr2/CLOB), or as an external table? Can you convert that to XMLType? Can you do the transformations?

Comment: Im a beginner in PL/SQL so i need a detailed procedure on how to read file from a folder to PL/SQL and further transformations. @Alex Poole

Comment: This site isn't to give tutorials or walkthroughs, it's to help you fix specific issues with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dummy_table (
  EventName,
  ReasonCode,
  ReasonCodeDescription,
  SystemTimeZoneOffset,
  EventDateTime
  -- ,...
)
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( xml, '//CISDocument/EventName' ),
       EXTRACTVALUE( xml, '//CISDocument/ReasonCode' ),
       EXTRACTVALUE( xml, '//CISDocument/ReasonCodeDescription' ),
       TO_NUMBER( EXTRACTVALUE( xml, '//CISDocument/SystemTimeZoneOffset' ) ),
       TO_DATE(
         EXTRACTVALUE( xml, '//CISDocument/SystemTimeZoneOffset' ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'
       )
       -- ,...
FROM   ( SELECT XMLType( your_clob_value ) AS XML FROM DUAL )
```